# How to use Hamcrest matchers with jUnit on Android

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit, hamcrest

I am somewhat new to Android and have been struggling for hours on how to include the Hamcrest matchers in my test project.  The code looks like it should run in Eclipse, no indicated errors.  But when I run the test, the Hamcrest classes are not loading.  I get "NoClassDefFoundError: org.hamcrest.Matchers".

I've spent the last 3 hours looking through the forums figuring that someone has encountered this before, but with no luck.  I must be doing something stupid as the IDE can see the classes, but the runtime doesn't.

Here is the test source:

```
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.equalTo;
import org.hamcrest.Matcher;
import android.test.InstrumentationTestCase;

public class AppDescLoaderTest extends InstrumentationTestCase {

  public void testHamcrest() {
    assertThat(3, equalTo(3));
  }
}
```

I've tried adding the hamcrest-all-1.2.jar as a Library and as an external jar.  Same result both ways, code looks fine in IDE but fails to load classes at runtime.

My theory is that the hamcrest.jar is not going with the .apk file and that is why its classes are not being loaded.  If that is true, how do I get it to be pushed over to the android along with the .apk file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you are on the current R17 tools, then...

> I've tried adding the hamcrest-all-1.2.jar as a Library and as an external jar. Same result both ways, code looks fine in IDE but fails to load classes at runtime.

Step #1: Undo all of that.

Step #2: Create a `libs/` directory in the root of your project.

Step #3: Put your JAR in `libs/`.

And you are done. This used to be the recipe just for command-line builds, but it is now the recipe for Eclipse-based builds as well.

Comment: That worked.  I also had to put a reference to the jar as an external jar or the IDE would not see the classes.  Now I get "Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1"

Comment: @wannabetester: "I also had to put a reference to the jar as an external jar or the IDE would not see the classes." -- that suggests that you are not on the R17 version of the development tools. Remove your reference as an external JAR. Right-click on the project, choose Build Path > Configure Build Path, click on the Libraries tab, click the Add JARs... button (note, *not* Add External JARs...), find the JAR inside your project's `libs/` directory, and add it.

Comment: Ok, I removed the jar file from the build path altogether and the IDE now recognizes the .jar simply because it is in the /libs folder.  Apparently all I needed to do before was refresh the IDE to recheck the /libs directory.  However, I still get the Dalvik error.  I believe there are other posts about that issue.  If you know the solution, please pass it on.  Meantime I'll try to find it.

Comment: @wannabetester: Check your Eclipse Console to see if there is more information about what failed. Or, do a command-line build, which I tend to find makes it easier for me to get at information about problems like this. The issue may well be peculiar to Hamcrest, which I had not heard of before your question and would have assumed referred to porcine heraldic symbols.

Comment: Hamcrest is a matcher library which is largely included in Junit 4.4 and beyond.  However, since Android limits me to Junit 3.x, I am trying to add the Hamcrest capabilities to improve the readability of my tests.  Anyway, there are some posts out there about the Dalvik issue, so I'll see if I can resolve the problem based on those other posts.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction about how to add libraries to my build.  I did not know about the /libs directory.

Comment: I never got hamcrest-all.jar to work.  So I downloaded ham crest-core.jar and ham crest-libraries.jar, did a clean/rebuild, and now everything seems to work just fine.